# add DCC metrics header with MailScanner/SpamAssassin

Tags: spamassassin, mailscanner

I have a working MailScanner 4.85.2 installation that is using DCC and reporting spamassassin DCC rule scores.

I'd like to have MailScanner or SpamAssassin add the DCC Metrics to a header. I cannot find any way to configure either to do so and would like to ask if anyone knows a way to do it, aside from running another dccproc in my procmailrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the SpamAssassin local.cf prefs file to get an X-Spam-DCC header added by SpamAssassin:

```
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::DCC
add_header all DCC _DCCB_:_DCCR_
endif
```